# Grunt css minify: .tmp folder breaks bootstrap glyphicons

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, gruntjs

Appears as this question has been asked quite often here already, yet I don't manage to make it run in my case:

Built an Angular app with Yeoman and SASS-Bootstrap, when I deploy it to my server glyphicons are missing due to a wrong path:

```
example.com/styles/.tmp/bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
```

There is no .tmp folder, I'm quite sure it's related to cssmin in my gruntfile.js. As I'm new to Yeoman/Grunt (used http://brunch.io before) I still can't figure it out.

main.scss:

```
$icon-font-path: "../bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/fonts/bootstrap/";
```

My grunt.js:

```
// Generated on 2015-02-14 using generator-angular 0.11.1
'use strict';

// # Globbing
// for performance reasons we're only matching one level down:
// 'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
// use this if you want to recursively match all subfolders:
// 'test/spec/**/*.js'

module.exports = function (grunt) {

// Load grunt tasks automatically
require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

// Time how long tasks take. Can help when optimizing build times
require('time-grunt')(grunt);

// Configurable paths for the application
var appConfig = {
app: require('./bower.json').appPath || 'app',
dist: 'dist'
};

// Define the configuration for all the tasks
grunt.initConfig({

// Project settings
yeoman: appConfig,

// Watches files for changes and runs tasks based on the changed files
watch: {
  bower: {
    files: ['bower.json'],
    tasks: ['wiredep']
  },
  js: {
    files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'],
    tasks: ['newer:jshint:all'],
    options: {
      livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
    }
  },
  jsTest: {
    files: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js'],
    tasks: ['newer:jshint:test', 'karma']
  },
  compass: {
    files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
    tasks: ['compass:server', 'autoprefixer']
  },
  gruntfile: {
    files: ['Gruntfile.js']
  },
  livereload: {
    options: {
      livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
    },
    files: [
      '<%= yeoman.app %>/{,*/}*.html',
      '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
      '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
    ]
  }
},

// The actual grunt server settings
connect: {
  options: {
    port: 9000,
    // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
    hostname: 'localhost',
    livereload: 35729
  },
  livereload: {
    options: {
      open: true,
      middleware: function (connect) {
        return [
          connect.static('.tmp'),
          connect().use(
            '/bower_components',
            connect.static('./bower_components')
          ),
          connect().use(
            '/app/styles',
            connect.static('./app/styles')
          ),
          connect.static(appConfig.app)
        ];
      }
    }
  },
  test: {
    options: {
      port: 9001,
      middleware: function (connect) {
        return [
          connect.static('.tmp'),
          connect.static('test'),
          connect().use(
            '/bower_components',
            connect.static('./bower_components')
          ),
          connect.static(appConfig.app)
        ];
      }
    }
  },
  dist: {
    options: {
      open: true,
      base: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
    }
  }
},

// Make sure code styles are up to par and there are no obvious mistakes
jshint: {
  options: {
    jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
    reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
  },
  all: {
    src: [
      'Gruntfile.js',
      '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'
    ]
  },
  test: {
    options: {
      jshintrc: 'test/.jshintrc'
    },
    src: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js']
  }
},

// Empties folders to start fresh
clean: {
  dist: {
    files: [{
      dot: true,
      src: [
        '.tmp',
        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*',
        '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git{,*/}*'
      ]
    }]
  },
  server: '.tmp'
},

// Add vendor prefixed styles
autoprefixer: {
  options: {
    browsers: ['last 1 version']
  },
  server: {
    options: {
      map: true,
    },
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
      src: '{,*/}*.css',
      dest: '.tmp/styles/'
    }]
  },
  dist: {
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
      src: '{,*/}*.css',
      dest: '.tmp/styles/'
    }]
  }
},

// Automatically inject Bower components into the app
wiredep: {
  app: {
    src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html'],
    ignorePath:  /\.\.\//
  },
  test: {
    devDependencies: true,
    src: '<%= karma.unit.configFile %>',
    ignorePath:  /\.\.\//,
    fileTypes:{
      js: {
        block: /(([\s\t]*)\/{2}\s*?bower:\s*?(\S*))(\n|\r|.)*?(\/{2}\s*endbower)/gi,
          detect: {
            js: /'(.*\.js)'/gi
          },
          replace: {
            js: '\'{{filePath}}\','
          }
        }
      }
  },
  sass: {
    src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
    ignorePath: /(\.\.\/){1,2}bower_components\//
  }
},

// Compiles Sass to CSS and generates necessary files if requested
compass: {
  options: {
    sassDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
    cssDir: '.tmp/styles',
    generatedImagesDir: '.tmp/images/generated',
    imagesDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
    javascriptsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
    fontsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/fonts',
    importPath: './bower_components',
    httpImagesPath: '/images',
    httpGeneratedImagesPath: '/images/generated',
    httpFontsPath: '/styles/fonts',
    relativeAssets: false,
    assetCacheBuster: false,
    raw: 'Sass::Script::Number.precision = 10\n'
  },
  dist: {
    options: {
      generatedImagesDir: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/generated'
    }
  },
  server: {
    options: {
      sourcemap: true
    }
  }
},

// Renames files for browser caching purposes
filerev: {
  dist: {
    src: [
      '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
      '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
      '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
      '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts/*'
    ]
  }
},

// Reads HTML for usemin blocks to enable smart builds that automatically
// concat, minify and revision files. Creates configurations in memory so
// additional tasks can operate on them
useminPrepare: {
  html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
  options: {
    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
    flow: {
      html: {
        steps: {
          js: ['concat', 'uglifyjs'],
          css: ['cssmin']
        },
        post: {}
      }
    }
  }
},

// Performs rewrites based on filerev and the useminPrepare configuration
usemin: {
  html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
  css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
  options: {
    assetsDirs: [
      '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
      '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images',
      '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles'
    ]
  }
},

// The following *-min tasks will produce minified files in the dist folder
// By default, your `index.html`'s <!-- Usemin block --> will take care of
// minification. These next options are pre-configured if you do not wish
// to use the Usemin blocks.
// cssmin: {
//   options: {
//     noRebase: true
//   }
//   dist: {
//     files: {
//       '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/main.css': [
//         '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css'
//       ]
//     }
//   }
// },
// uglify: {
//   dist: {
//     files: {
//       '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js': [
//         '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js'
//       ]
//     }
//   }
// },
// concat: {
//   dist: {}
// },

imagemin: {
  dist: {
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
      src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif}',
      dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
    }]
  }
},

svgmin: {
  dist: {
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
      src: '{,*/}*.svg',
      dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
    }]
  }
},

htmlmin: {
  dist: {
    options: {
      collapseWhitespace: true,
      conservativeCollapse: true,
      collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
      removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
      removeOptionalTags: true
    },
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
      src: ['*.html', 'views/{,*/}*.html'],
      dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
    }]
  }
},

// ng-annotate tries to make the code safe for minification automatically
// by using the Angular long form for dependency injection.
ngAnnotate: {
  dist: {
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: '.tmp/concat/scripts',
      src: '*.js',
      dest: '.tmp/concat/scripts'
    }]
  }
},

// Replace Google CDN references
cdnify: {
  dist: {
    html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/*.html']
  }
},

// Copies remaining files to places other tasks can use
copy: {
  dist: {
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      dot: true,
      cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
      dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
      src: [
        '*.{ico,png,txt}',
        '.htaccess',
        '*.html',
        'views/{,*/}*.html',
        'images/{,*/}*.{webp}',
        'styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*'
      ]
    }, {
      expand: true,
      cwd: '.tmp/images',
      dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images',
      src: ['generated/*']
    }, {
      expand: true,
      cwd: '.',
      src: 'bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/fonts/bootstrap/*',
      dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
    }]
  },
  styles: {
    expand: true,
    cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
    dest: '.tmp/styles/',
    src: '{,*/}*.css'
  }
},

// Run some tasks in parallel to speed up the build process
concurrent: {
  server: [
    'compass:server'
  ],
  test: [
    'compass'
  ],
  dist: [
    'compass:dist',
    'imagemin',
    'svgmin'
  ]
},

// Test settings
karma: {
  unit: {
    configFile: 'test/karma.conf.js',
    singleRun: true
  }
}
});


grunt.registerTask('serve', 'Compile then start a connect web server',     function (target) {
if (target === 'dist') {
  return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
}

grunt.task.run([
  'clean:server',
  'wiredep',
  'concurrent:server',
  'autoprefixer:server',
  'connect:livereload',
  'watch'
]);
});

  grunt.registerTask('server', 'DEPRECATED TASK. Use the "serve" task instead', function (target) {
grunt.log.warn('The `server` task has been deprecated. Use `grunt serve` to start a server.');
grunt.task.run(['serve:' + target]);
  });

grunt.registerTask('test', [
'clean:server',
'wiredep',
'concurrent:test',
'autoprefixer',
'connect:test',
'karma'
]);

grunt.registerTask('build', [
'clean:dist',
'wiredep',
'useminPrepare',
'concurrent:dist',
'autoprefixer',
'concat',
'ngAnnotate',
'copy:dist',
'cdnify',
'cssmin',
'uglify',
'filerev',
'usemin',
'htmlmin'
]);

grunt.registerTask('default', [
'newer:jshint',
'test',
'build'
]);
};
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I needed to change the path in the main.scss into

```
  `$icon-font-path: "/bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/fonts/bootstrap/";`.
```

And the stupid me forgot to clear the browser cache.